# PHP: remove empty array strings in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
$aryMain = array(array('hello','bye'), array('',''),array('',''));
```

It is formed by reading a csv file and the array('','') are the empty rows at the end of the file.

How can I remove them?

I've tried:

```
$aryMain = array_filter($aryMain);
```

But it is not working :(

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not just skip those empty lines in the first place?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To add to Rikesh's answer:

```
<?php
$aryMain = array(array('hello','bye'), array('',''),array('','')); 
$aryMain = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $aryMain));
print_r($aryMain);

?>
```

Sticking his code into another array_filter will get rid of the entire arrays themselves.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => bye
        )

)
```

Compared to:

```
$aryMain = array_map('array_filter', $aryMain);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => hello
            [1] => bye
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: @MiguelMas Keep in mind that strings like `'0'` will get removed as well in this way.

Answer (score 10):

Use [**array_map**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) along with array_filter,

```
$array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $array));
```

Or just create a `array_filter_recursive` function

```
function array_filter_recursive($input) 
{ 
   foreach ($input as &$value) 
    { 
      if (is_array($value)) 
      { 
         $value = array_filter_recursive($value); 
      } 
   }     
   return array_filter($input); 
}
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PlIoJA)**

Note: that this will remove items comprising '0' (i.e. string with a numeral zero). Just pass `'strlen'` as a second parameter to keep `0`

Comment: Upvoted because of strlen tip!

Answer (score 2):

Apply `array_filter()` on the main array and then once more on the inner elements:

```
$aryMain = array_filter($aryMain, function($item) {
    return array_filter($item, 'strlen');
});
```

The inner `array_filter()` specifically uses `strlen()` to determine whether the element is empty; otherwise it would remove `'0'` as well.

To determine the emptiness of an array you could also use `array_reduce()`:

```
array_filter($aryMain, function($item) {
    return array_reduce($item, function(&$res, $item) {
        return $res + strlen($item);
    }, 0);
});
```

Whether that's more efficient is arguable, but it should save some memory :)