# Count rows with data in csv using PHP

Tags: php, csv

I want to count total number of rows with data in csv.
I did following:

```
<?php echo count(file('example.csv',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES |` `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)); ?>
```

Here, if all the values are only in first column then output is correct.
eg. `Row1Col1='a'` & `Row4Col1='b'` **o/p=2** correct because data in rows are

```
Row1->'a',Row2->'',Row3->'',Row4->'b'
```

But if values are in different column then get wrong output.
eg. `Ro1Col3='a'` & `Row4Col1='b'` **o/p=4** wrong (want correct output is 2) because data in rows are

```
Row1->'a', Row2->',,' Row3->',,' Row4->'b'.
```

Thanks,
Jaydeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the PHP function [function.str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

You can use [function.array_filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536960/php-remove-empty-array-strings-in-multidimensional-array) to remove any `null` elements within your CSV.

```
<?php

    $csv_complete_contents = array_map('str_getcsv', file('example.csv'));
    $csv_complete_filtered = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $csv_complete_contents));
    $csv_num_rows = count($csv_complete_filtered);

    echo $csv_num_rows;

?>
```