# How to remove null values in multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, null, filtering, php-5.6

I want to remove null values from this array.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array( [fcmToken] => 123 )
    [1] => Array( [fcmToken] => )
    [2] => Array( [fcmToken] => 789 )
)
```

Expected Results

```
Array(
    [0] => Array( [fcmToken] => 123 )
    [1] => Array( [fcmToken] => 789 )
)
```

Comment: `123` and `789` ?? where it come from?

Comment: You can do it using print_r(array_values(array_filter($entry)));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we are using `foreach` to iterate over values and using `$value` for `non-empty $value["fcmToken"]`

```
$result=array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(!empty($value["fcmToken"]))
    {
        $result[]=$value;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fcmToken] => dfqVhqdqhpk
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fcmToken] => dfgdfhqdqhpk
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) with a callback:

```
$r = array_filter($array, function($v) { return !empty($v['fcmToken']); });
```

For checking exactly `null`:

```
$r = array_filter($array, function($v) { return !is_null($v['fcmToken']); });
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and easy single line solution for filter multidimensional array like below.

```
$aryMain = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $aryMain));
```

I hope this solution is work for you. for more detail please visit below link.

[PHP: remove empty array strings in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536960/php-remove-empty-array-strings-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Rather than doing an exact code copy-paste from another answer on SO, you should just flag/vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

> Danger! Do not trust **empty()** when dealing with numbers (or number-ish) values that could be zero!!!  The same is true with using **array_filter** without a specific filtering parameter (as several answers on this page are using).

Look at how you can get the wrong output:

Bad Method:

```
$array = array(
    array("fcmToken" => '0'),
    array("fcmToken" => 123),
    array("fcmToken" => ''),
    array("fcmToken" => 789),
    array("fcmToken" => 0)
);

$result=array();                         // note, this line is unnecessary
foreach($array as $key => $value){       // note, $key is unnecessary
    if(!empty($value["fcmToken"])){      // this is not a reliable method
        $result[]=$value;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'fcmToken' => 123,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'fcmToken' => 789,
  ),
)
```

The zeros got swallowed up!

---

### This is how it should be done:

Instead, you should use `strlen()` to check the values:

Method #1: foreach()

```
foreach($array as $sub){
    if(strlen($sub["fcmToken"])){
        $result[]=$sub;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Method #2: `array_filter()` w/ anonymous function and `array_values()` for consistency

```
var_export(array_values(array_filter($array,function($a){return strlen($a['fcmToken']);})));
```

Output for either method:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'fcmToken' => '0',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'fcmToken' => 123,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'fcmToken' => 789,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'fcmToken' => 0,
  ),
)
```

[Demonstration of bad method and two good methods](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6fce4d919a4185cdc0d8c5ae101013232cb9e9c2).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). Check below code :

```
$entry = array(
    array("fcmToken" => 'dfqVhqdqhpk'),
    array("fcmToken" => ''),
    array("fcmToken" => 'dfgdfhqdqhpk'),
);
echo "<pre>";
$entry = array_values(array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $entry)));
print_r($entry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this recursive function which iterates over any subarray and remove all elements with a null-value.

```
function removeNullValues ($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $entry) {
        if (is_array($entry)) {
            $array[$key] = removeNullValues($entry);
            if ($array[$key] === []) {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        } else {
            if ($entry === null) {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using array_map() to apply the filter to every array in the array.