# Cannot remove null elements from nested array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array, **$row2**.

In **$row2** two arrays are present. The output of  **$row2** is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Proposal_id] => 9
            [row] => 1
            [col1] => 2
            [col2] => 2
            [col3] =>
            [col4] =>
            [col5] =>
            [Type] => customtbl
            [Invoice_term] =>
            [Qoute] =>
            [Rate_per_hour] =>
            [Total] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Proposal_id] => 9
            [row] => 2
            [col1] => 3
            [col2] => 4
            [col3] =>
            [col4] =>
            [col5] =>
            [Type] => customtbl
            [Invoice_term] =>
            [Qoute] =>
            [Rate_per_hour] =>
            [Total] =>
        )

)
```

I want to remove null elements from the array, but I can't do this.

I tried the following methods:

```
array_filter($row2);
array_filter($row2, function($var){return !is_null($var);});
array_diff($rows2, array("null", ""));
```

Comment: Try `$row2 = array_map('array_filter', $row2);`

Comment: @billyonecan that works, altho could have unexpected results as it will also remove zeros.

Comment: @billyonecan please post your comment as an answer to this question

Comment: not working for me
btw thanku for your feedback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove empty values from multidimensional array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214531/how-to-remove-empty-values-from-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/q/16536960/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/43694052/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've an one liner solution to filter out `null` values from multidimensional array if you use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) along with [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php),

```
    $array = [
    ['Proposal_id' => 9,
     'row' => 1,
     'col1' => 2, 
     'col2' => 2, 
     'col3' => null,
     'col4' => null,
     'col5' =>  null,
     'Type' => 'customtbl',
     'Invoice_term' => null,  
     'Qoute' => null,
     'Rate_per_hour' => null,  
     'Total' => null,
    ],
    [   
        'Proposal_id' => 9,
        'row' => 1,
        'col1' => 2, 
        'col2' => 2 ,
        'col3' => null,
        'col4' => null,
        'col5' =>  null,
        'Type' => 'customtbl',
        'Invoice_term' => null,  
        'Qoute' => null,
        'Rate_per_hour' => null,  
        'Total' => null,
    ]
];
$af = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $array));
print '<pre>';
print_r($af);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Proposal_id] => 9
            [row] => 1
            [col1] => 2
            [col2] => 2
            [Type] => customtbl
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Proposal_id] => 9
            [row] => 1
            [col1] => 2
            [col2] => 2
            [Type] => customtbl
        )

)
```

**DEMO** : https://eval.in/975240

Comment: @dani have you seen the demo? It should work..why it is not working for you? can you explain?

Comment: your code is working with your array but not work with me

Comment: i'm fetching the data from the database may be thats way not working

Comment: Yeah that could be a reason. But I've posted the answer based on your array structure on the question's code. Best of luck..

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_filter` within `array_map`.
Just remember you may want to run a different conditional rather than `if($value)` as this will validate against not only nulls, but zeros and empty strings.

```
array_map(function($var) {
    return array_filter($var, function($value) {
        if ( !is_null($value) )
            return $value;
    });
},$row2);
```